# How to increment + 1 on a long button click?

Tags: java, android, timer, onclick, intervals

I have a `Button` and a `TextView`. When I hold this `Button` for 1 second or so, the `TextView` should increment 1 by 1 in a 0.5 seconds interval.

I'm kind of lost and don't know what I should use here. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I have an onClick event too. When I make a small click it adds 0.1 (this is already working).

This is what I've come out so far.. but no results. The activity just stop working.

```
btnPlusPastryDosage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {           
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motion) 
        {
            Handler myHandler = new Handler();                          

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
            {                                               
                public void run() 
                {                       
                    String valueStr = txtPastryDosage.getText().toString();
                    valueStr = valueStr.replace(',', '.');

                    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(valueStr);                
                    value = value.subtract(new BigDecimal("1"));

                    if(value.doubleValue() >= 0) txtPastryDosage.setText(String.valueOf(value));                        
                }
            };

            while(motion.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
            }                                                                       

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just posted the code.. I though I knew what I was doing but it went totally wrong. Added more info too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnClick, make a Handler to post a Runnable that sets the height and width of the button, and increments it. Save the height/width somewhere. Each post method of the handler should check if the button is still pressed. If not, remove all callbacks.

Handler: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
Runnable: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: You probably want to avoid a while loop like that. In your runnable check if motion.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and then remove all callbacks myHandler.removeCallbacks(Runnable r) from the handler if so. If not, go through the actions of the runnable. This way you are not posting a ton of times, just every .5 seconds. This is the right direction though.

Comment: The first thing you do is post the runnable again with the handler at the start of the run() method. This way it is .5 seconds at a time. Don't use the while loop to do it. Make an if/else block in run() to check if you should still be running it, i.e. that the button is still pressed.

Comment: Sorry I took REALLY LONG to answer you. Your answer was perfect, it really helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with the android UI libraries, but I believe it should go something like this: Create a timer with an interval of .5 seconds, and set it so it is disabled at launch. Add an event handler to the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) event of your button, which is triggered "when a touch event is dispatched to this view", meaning when a finger is pressed and when a finger is released. if it's when a finger is pressed, enable the timer. if it's when a finger is released, disable it.

Comment: I got the pressed and release thing, made some tests. But about the timer, can you provide some example? I can't seem to make it a 0.5 interval, just like that. Maybe I should use a Runnable (AJcodez suggestion)?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have a boolean flag that is turned on once the button is clicked then is turned off when the button is let go of.  When the flag is turned on, have a (probably swing is easiest to use here) Timer start sending out events at half second intervals, when your listener gets them, make it increase the variable displayed by your textview increase by one.  When the flag is turned off, stop the timer.

EDIT: My bad, didn't see the Android tag - however, this will work for regular Java.